# Jenkinsfile: Ask for input in a post condition block

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'd like my Jenkins deploy pipeline to

1. attempt a shell command,
2. provide an input step if that command fails, and then
3. re-try the command and continue the pipeline on "ok".

Here's the (start) of my attempt to do so.

```
    stage('Get config') {
        steps {
            sh 'aws appconfig get-configuration [etc etc]'
        }
        post {
            failure {
                input {
                    message "There is no config deployed for this environment. Set it up in AWS and then continue."
                    ok "Continue"
                }
                steps {
                    sh 'aws appconfig get-configuration [etc etc]'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When running the `input` directly in a `stage`, this example does show the input. However, when putting it in the `post { failure }`, I get this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

WorkflowScript: 27: Missing required parameter: "message" @ line 27, column 21.

                       input {

                       ^
```

Do Jenkins declarative pipelines allow `input` in `post`?

Is there a better way to accomplish my desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post):

> [Post-condition](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post-conditions) blocks contain [steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-steps) the same as the [steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#steps) section.

This means that [input](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#input) in your code is interpreted as step instead of directive.

---

Solution using script syntax (try/catch would also be fine there):

```
stage('Get config') {
    steps {
        script {
            def isConfigOk = sh( script: 'aws appconfig get-configuration [etc etc]', returnStatus: true) == 0

            if ( ! isConfigOk ) {
                input (message: "There is no config deployed for this environment. Set it up in AWS and then continue.", ok: "Continue")
                sh 'aws appconfig get-configuration [etc etc]'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using post section:

```
stage('Get config') {
    steps {
        sh 'aws appconfig get-configuration [etc etc]'
    }
    post {
        failure {
            input (message: "There is no config deployed for this environment. Set it up in AWS and then continue.", ok: "Continue")
            sh 'aws appconfig get-configuration [etc etc]'
        }
    } 
}
```

---

Remember that your approach with post section will **ignore outcome** of second `aws appconfig get-configuration [etc etc]` **and fail**. There is a way to change this behaviour but I wouldn't call this solution any clean.